# can't install scipy - freezes on "Running setup.py install for scipy"

Tags: python, scipy, pip

when I run

```
sudo pip install -U scipy
```

it is first downloaded and then it goes on to show

```
Running setup.py install for scipy
```

but it freezes there. I tried upgrading pip itself. Worked fine. My pip version is 1.5.4

The only error i get is InsecurePlatforWarning. The complete output looks like this:

```
tom@tom-ThinkPad-Edge-E430:~$ sudo pip install -U scipy
The directory '/home/tom/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory
is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled.
Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If
executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/home/tom/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not
owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled.
check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with
sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Collecting scipy
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:90:
InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available.
This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and
may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see
https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
InsecurePlatformWarning
Downloading scipy-0.16.1.tar.gz (12.2MB)
   100% |████████████████████████████████| 12.2MB 32kB/s 
Installing collected packages: scipy
   Running setup.py install for scipy
```

Comment: How long did you wait? scipy comes with a lot of C/C++/Fortran extentions that can take a long time to compile. You can display the compiler messages using `~$ pip install -v scipy`.

Comment: yes you are right. it took several minutes but it's finished now

Comment: the same can happen when you install `sklearn`

Answer (score 73, accepted):

It took unexpectedly long, but it finished after several minutes. So problem solved.

Comment: Same here - took around 4-5 minutes to install.

Comment: This is probably the simplest answer I've ever upvoted. But a look at `top` showed 100% CPU utilization by cc1plus, so I assume compilation is hard at work.

Comment: Took me about 10 minutes - 21/FEB/2018

Comment: It's been going for over an hour on my Raspberry Pi and CPU utilisation is 5%, so this actually can be a bug.

Comment: for me, it takes more than 3 hrs to complete.

Comment: For me it was taking close to eternity on pretty solid MacBook PRO, my guess is it was due to the fact it ran in docker which limits resources available ...

Comment: Tried installing via pip (with --no-cache-dir option). Pi hang up completely after 4 hours, and that's with a custom heatsink added. Without it pi hangs up after two hours. No luck on that method of installation.

Answer (score 3):

Do

```
sudo apt-get install python-scipy
```

for python2

or

```
sudo apt-get install python3-scipy
```

if you don't care about the version. Installs within a few seconds on RPI3

Answer (score 0):

Increasing the swap size from 100M to 1024M resolved the problem on a Raspberry Pi 3 with 1G RAM. Still took a long time (~1h) but did not freeze anymore.

(found this hint on https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/9434)